Markers don't show in maps flutter

When I change icon for mark clinic doesn't print in map.

And when I not change icon the output give me default mark.

supposed to when call this function the mark clinics in this list (markersDermatologist) is show in map and this already work without change icon.


but when change icon , function is not working.
  Future<void> getNearbyDermatologyClinics() async {
    final BitmapDescriptor descriptor = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
      ImageConfiguration(size: Size(48, 48)), // Adjust size as needed
      'assets/ClinicsMark.png',
    );
    for (var clinic in markersDermatologist) {
        markersClinics.add(Marker(
          icon: descriptor,
          markerId: MarkerId('clinic_${clinic.name}'),
          position: LatLng(clinic.latitude, clinic.longitude),
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
              title: clinic.name,
              onTap: () {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) =>
                        AlertDialog(
                          content: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(Icons.person_rounded,
                                      color: ColorManager.primaryColor),
                                  Text(
                                    clinic.name,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        color: ColorManager.primaryColor),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ), //name

                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(Icons.phone,
                                      color: ColorManager.primaryColor),
                                  Text(
                                    clinic.phone as String,
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ), //phone
                            ],
                          ),
                        ));
              }),
        ));
      setState(() {});
    }
  }



Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
